# NoClassDefFoundError: Crashlytics FirebaseInfo

Tags: java, android, proguard, crashlytics, android-proguard

I am trying to enable `minifyEnabled` on my app and I have resolved all the compile time warnings but this happens when I run it:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lio/fabric/sdk/android/services/common/FirebaseInfo;
at com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider.onCreate(CrashlyticsInitProvider.java:22)
at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1917)
at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1892)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6239)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5805)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5722)
```

This is my `proguard-rules.pro`:

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep public class * extends java.lang. 
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.**
```

Comment: Mike from Firebase here. If you can share tour app's full build.gradle, that would help!